# Does Data smell?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

It's pretty clear Data can see, hear, and feel stimuli; in fact his [sight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53635/22917) is better than the average humanoid's. But what about his olfactory abilities?  Can he smell or taste anything?

Comment: You should have asked "Does Data smell?" and waited for the comments.

Comment: @OrganicMarble done- what a brilliant idea!

Comment: Followup question "*How* does Data smell?"  Hightest voted answer: "Terrible!"

Comment: @OrganicMarble http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126946/does-data-smell

Comment: Does Data smell? Yes, possibly like oil and antifreeze. bah dum bum

Comment: I have rolled back an edit that conflicts with intent of the title.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've divided this answer into his abilities to taste and smell:

## He can't taste...

In *TNG* 'Hero Worship', Data says

> DATA: I would gladly risk feeling bad at times if it also meant that I could also taste my dessert.

This strongly indicates he can't 'taste' anything he eats or drinks.

### ...but he can detect

Nevertheless, I suspect he has the ability to detect chemicals ingested.  In *Generations* he experiences 'hate' when he drinks a beverage.  The only logical explanation of this is that he could detect the chemicals being ingested, which triggered an emotional response.

## He can smell

It's alluded to a couple of times that he does have the ability to smell things:

1. In *TNG* 'Phantasms':

> DATA: Everything seems to remind me of the nightmare. Objects, sounds, smells. And now I have seen elements of the dream in a waking state. I cannot explain it.

2. *TNG* 'The Offspring':

> DATA: Yes, very good, Lal. You have correctly processed the sense of touch. **There are many fascinating experiences I wish to share with you.**
>
> LAL: Painting.
>
> DATA: No, that is a flower, Lal. Inhale.
>
> LAL: Smell!
>
> DATA: Yes.

The above passage would also strongly indicate Data can smell.

So, I would expect Data can both taste and smell stimuli, at least in the form of having functional chemoreceptors.  The full experience of taste and smells though elude him without the emotion chip, as all he experiences is analysis and identification of the presence of chemicals, a bit like a shopping list rather than a necessary sensation.

Comment: @N_Soong: Data also was able to smell the bubble gum scent of the Roger Maris baseball card in the episode "The Most Toys".

Comment: @N_Soong: Data picked up on the smell as soon as Kivas opened the little door covering the card and later when Data was alone, Data opened the door himself for another sniff.

Comment: *"I sense injuries. The data could be called 'pain'."*  – Terminator 2

Comment: @sfhq_sf well then that is indeed another piece of evidence- good pick up!

Comment: Let's just pretend that Data with emotions never happened. It's not quite as bad as "Threshold," but it was horrible nonetheless.

Comment: To be fair, tasting *is* the biological method of detecting. "Taste" is, in fact, what detection of chemicals in food feels like. Whether we like or dislike the taste of something is how we tell good stuff from bad stuff. Since Data doesn't eat food, none of it makes a difference to him - so he can detect chemicals (i.e. taste them), but cannot attach feelings to the "taste" the way we do.

Comment: @MishaRosnach indeed, but it would be inaccurate to say taste is detection. It's that, but more so the experience associated with that detection

Comment: @N_Soong That's a slightly awkward argument to make. Biologically, we have an experience associated with every detection - an experience of taste, an experience of color, tone, volume, etc. We don't detect anything in terms of numbers and code. We also have no experience with the sensation of detection outside of our own. We know that a computer can detect stuff and express information about it, but we have no way of knowing what right numbers and wrong numbers might "feel" like to a sophisticated computer. It may very well be that all hierarchical detection is experiential on some level.

Comment: Data can taste, and does so in Generations. The comment from Hero Worship was directed a child. He was likely referring to his ability to *enjoy* a flavor (or hate one, as he did in Generations) as "taste" rather than the ability to collect and process information with his tongue. Without the emotion chip, he can have the experience without forming an opinion it one way or the other.

Comment: To piggyback @T.J.L. comment, taste for humans is simply the chemo-receptors on our tongue responding to chemicals in the foods we eat. Data's tongue can perform the same function (the emotion chip didn't replace his tongue) but it was Data's ability to feel the effect of the foods he eats that he wanted in 'Hero Worship'.

Comment: @MishaRosnach I disagree; I think both we and Data would detect through electronic impulses, tasting or smelling adds qualia to those detections

Comment: @N_Soong And how would you know that something has sugar in it without the qualia of "sweet?" That's the difference between "detection" and "reaction." Water *reacts* to sugar by becoming viscous - but it does not *detect* it, because there is no qualification of data happening. The receptors in our tongue react to sugar as well, but our brain *qualifies* it - "this is sugar." And the sweet sensation is what this qualia "feels" like to the computer that is our brain. It is essentially the sensation of sorting data. *Detection* and *qualia* are innately linked.

Answer (score 17):

As we see in the episode [TNG: Angel One](http://tng.trekcore.com/episodes/scripts/115.txt), Data is perfectly capable of smelling, and accurately *distinguishing* a variety of smells:

> Tasha pacing; Troi and Riker sitting; Data examining knickknacks. Data's attention falls on an atomizer. Squeezing the ball, he gets a face full of mist.
>
> **DATA:** [Sniffs] *Interesting. An alcohol-based synthetic, artificially reproducing a floral scent.*
>
> **TROI:** *It is called perfume, Data.*

[image: GIF of Data sniffing the perfume]

and from [TNG: The Most Toys](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/170.txt)

> **FAJO:** *The very first Basotile ever created by the Rodulans... centuries old. Priceless. A vase carved by the late Mark Off-Zel on
> Sirrie Four. The only known Roger Maris trading card from Earth circa
> 1962... smell it...*
>
> [Data does, reacts...]
>
> **FAJO:** *Bubblegum... I've preserved the scent...*

[image: Fajo opening the cabinet with the baseball card, Data sniffing]

And [TNG: Relics](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Relics_(episode)) (although he's apparently unable to discern the Aldebaran whiskey by smell alone). From the [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/230.txt);

> Data is unable to read the label. He removes the cap and sniffs the
> contents... but still doesn't know what to make of it... he looks at
> the liquid and finally tells Scott the only thing he knows for
> certain.

[image: Data sniffs the bottle, raises his eyebrows]

Comment: In TNG's *Relics*, he also [smells the alcohol he gives Scotty](https://youtu.be/r0RuRJOQa8M?t=20s), but is unable to identify it and simply concludes "It is green".

Answer (score 2):

I think the eternal rule for Data is he imitates almost all human capabilities, but can't "enjoy" them.  I'll lay odds he could taste soup, tell you ingredient, in exact percentage, but couldn't tell you if it's delicious. He can probably identify breeds of roses by their smell, but can't say if he likes the scent. He plays violin, and can likely play any piece ever written, but can't any which one he thinks is better than the other.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your rose example. Data would be able to smell it, but I also think that he'd say that he "neither likes it, nor dislikes it." He wouldn't be unsure. Data knows he has no emotions; thus, "liking" is something he can't do.