# Was Geordi's VISOR capable of displaying only the visible spectrum?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Geordi's VISOR is clearly capable of viewing a [wide range of electromagnetic signals](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96385/how-does-geordi-laforges-visor-work?noredirect=1&lq=1) *including* visual wavelengths.

Would it be possible for him to ***intentionally limit his VISOR to just the visible light spectrum, allowing him to see what a normally-sighted human would be able to see?***

---

I recall that in *First Contact* his upgrade essentially delivered him the same representation, so as a followup, **is it perhaps that he simply *prefers* all the extra information to be represented?**

Comment: Also you might find this interesting; [Who can see better: Geordi or Data?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53635/who-can-see-better-geordi-or-data)

Comment: This has nice pictures; [Why does Geordi La Forge's VISOR see a wide subspace spectrum and not just visible light?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36107/why-does-geordi-la-forges-visor-see-a-wide-subspace-spectrum-and-not-just-visib?rq=1)

Comment: @Valorum: I'm not seeing how this is a duplicate. That answer agrees with this question that Geordi's visor allows him to see much of the spectrum, but doesn't seem to mention whether he's forced to see the entire spectrum at once, or whether he can focus on different parts of the spectrum for better resolution of certain details or, in the case of this question, to just be more normal.

Comment: In your second link, the questions says "But every so often Geordi will speak of how frustrated he is that he can't see a sunset or other things the way regularly sighted people do". A citation for that would make a good (negative) answer to this question.

Comment: @MichaelS - I think you're right. That being said, it needs a re-write.

Comment: Hmm. I suspect the issue is that after having lived his life with the full spectrum, seeing just the visible range would be enormously limiting for him. Like if you were suddenly confined to 1% of your normal visual spectrum

Comment: @Valorum  I'm more than happy to rewrite; can you give me a suggestion to help me out!

Comment: @1252748 - I've done an edit to make the question 'pop' a little more. Have a read through and if you want to make any changes or roll back, you can use the [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/143999/edit) button.

Comment: On several occasions it has been said that Geordi cannot control the flood of information from his visor and he has learned to sort out the noise. In "The Minds Eye" this is exploited by the Romulan's who brainwash Geordi by subjecting him to images which he cannot resist. Geordi get's real vision on two occasions that I can remember. Once in "Hide in Q" when Riker has Q powers and gives him sight and once in Insurrection when the metaphasic energy repairs his natural sight. Both times he is happy to return to his visor.

Answer (score 9):

From the [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/120.txt) of Season 1: Episode 20, "Heart of Glory," as posted on [st-minutiae.com](http://www.st-minutiae.com/); while Geordi is transmitting the VISOR data stream back to the Enterprise bridge via the [visual acuity transmitter](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Visual_acuity_transmitter) (emphasis added):

> **Picard:** Geordi. What was that? Over to the left.
>
> **Geordi:** What?
>
> **Picard:** That—right there? No—back. Yes. That—right there. What is it?
>
> **Geordi:** It's Commander Riker.
>
> **Picard:** To me it's just an undefined upright form, standing in a wild visual frenzy. Can you filter out the extraneous information?
>
> **Geordi:** ***No, I get it all simultaneously.***
>
> **Picard:** It's a jumble. How can you make heads or tails of it?
>
> **Geordi:** ***I select what I want to see and disregard the rest.***
>
> **Picard:** How is that possible?
>
> **Geordi:** How, in a noisy room, can you pick out one specific voice or sound?
>
> **Picard:** It's something you learn.
>
> **Geordi:** Exactly, It's something I have learned.

Thus, I would argue that Geordi **cannot** restrict the bandwidth of the data stream the VISOR passes to his visual cortex, at least not the VISOR of the ST:TNG show itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Geordi can see neutrinos.**

[These particles are not light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino), but are a form of matter so small and they interact so sparingly with other matter that they could fly through a light-year of Uranium bricks and not even notice. That's how ghostly they are. A trillion of them pass through your eyeball every second on their journey from the center of the Sun to the Cosmos.

In the episode, *[The Enemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Enemy_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))* (season 3, episode 7), Geordi and an enemy Romulan soldier are trapped on a harsh planet and must depend on each other to survive. The Enterprise launches a probe onto the planet's surface that would send **a neutrino signal that could be detected by La Forge's VISOR**.

To my best knowledge, this is the **only** episode in the entire series that mentioned Geordi can see anything other than photons. (Feel free to mention any other episode if you can think of one.)

Comment: But the question is asking about "only visible light". It seems you have an implicit argument there, that if he can tune in ti see neutrinos, he can as well tune to see only visible light.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Ah, I see your point. I originally interpreted the question differently. My answer was more to point out that if he can see neutrinos, then he can see more than just visible light.